I have this error on connecting with my Azure database and doing PGVector Storing using Langchain for my LLM. How do I solve this?
from langchain_core.documents import Document
from langchain_postgres import PGVector
from langchain_postgres.vectorstores import PGVector

# See docker command above to launch a postgres instance with pgvector enabled.
connection = f"postgresql+psycopg://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}:5432/force-embeddings?ssl_cipher" # Uses psycopg3!
collection_name = "vectors_jap_small"


vector_store = PGVector(
    embeddings=embeddings,
    collection_name=collection_name,
    connection=connection,
    use_jsonb=True,
)

Error Message:
SQLAlchemy connection failed: (psycopg.OperationalError) [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Is this error because I made a wrong format? or is this because of the Restrictions of the database. I do not have full access to the database since I am not an Admin
I need to be able to connect to the Azure database, my solution is show above

connection = f"postgresql+psycopg://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}:5432/force-embeddings?ssl_cipher"
This line seems to be the problem. You should be using the proper credentials and format. Try to connect using psycopg2

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
